# Has the Ambiance theme been ported to GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, ambiance

Has the Ambiance theme we were used to see on older versions of Ubuntu been ported to Gnome Shell in Ubuntu 11.10? Does it come included when one installs the `gnome-shell` package?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no official port of the Ambiance theme to the GNOME Shell yet. A third party theme can be found [here](http://half-left.deviantart.com/art/GNOME-Shell-Ubuntu-Ambience-210264151), but it doesn't work with GNOME 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

there is this G-S theme http://gnome-shell.deviantart.com/gallery/?set=28081982&offset=72#/d3h6ouv and ambiance supports gtk3 as well :-)
or this one 
http://browse.deviantart.com/?qh=&section=&global=1&q=gnome-shell+ambiance#/d4l4i0n
quite alot at deviant art esp by half-left :-)